# Blocking users from copying files to non-domain computers

Tags: windows, domain, blocking

I work in a windows domain and I'm trying to see if it's possible to help secure data by blocking a user's ability to copy documents and other such files from a domain computer to a non-domain device? And vice-versa?

As long as it didn't prevent file downloads would be ideal but I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: You can disable unregistered USB devices.  You can disable optical drives.  How are they copying the files now?

Comment: Well more specifically from a domain pc to any cloud service. So keep them from being able to upload anything would be more accurate. We're looking into how to block usb storage devices. Optical burning is already disabled.

Comment: You could block list certain sites?

Comment: @Nartuck - So block those domains at the firewall.  We know nothing about you network.  How you do that is up to you.  The best way to avoid files from being copied, to outside of the domain, don't allow computers connected to a private network be connected to the internet.  Seperate your work functions if you have to seperate networks and domains.

Comment: Data Exfiltration controls are almost impossible to get right. Enterprises spend billions of dollars per year, but there are sooooo many pitfalls, that even a single absolutely required exception opens the sluice gates. for instance, most encrypted content can't be examined in a network stream, so tools like websense can either block all encrypted traffic, or forgo inspection, so a simple ssl proxy accessed on :443 could cut straight through. VPN protocols and SSH tunnels are important to admins everywhere so its difficult to block encrypted content at all.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yeah we've suggested blocking the cloud service domains (some already are) but higher ups don't want to breed such a culture of restricting access. I know, you can't have secure AND full freedom but hey, who am I to argue. I'm simply the messenger. I couldn't think of anything better than firewall rules as well. Aside from account lock-downs.

Comment: @Nartuck - So in those cases of the accessible cloud services, users will be able to publish said documents to those services, and once that happens you have no control.  One possible solution would be to have a dedicated machine and perhaps user, to access those services, the general idea is you could allow those services but use physical control to the machine itself.  Make people come to you to access these services, they are free to be used, just not without some control.

Comment: @Ramhound - Not a bad idea. Maybe a larger scale implementation (more than one) could work with some finagling. Or maybe permissions to allow users access after admin permission. I'd really like a setup where restriction isn't the mood but monitoring and alerting when someone is moving something to the cloud would be nice. But the management of such a thing sounds daunting...